# Where does Odoo 9 physically store the `image` field of `res.partner` records in the database?

Tags: postgresql, odoo

I can't find the `image` column in `res_partner` table in an Odoo 9 PostgreSQL database? Where does Odoo 9 store this image field?

Comment: It might be worth specifying the version of Odoo you are using. The storage location changed in version 9.0

Comment: yes I am using Odoo 9.0

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As of Odoo 9, many `binary` fields have been modified to be stored inside the `ir.attachment` model (`ir_attachment` table). This was done in order to benefit from the filesystem storage (and deduplication properties) and avoid bloating the database.

This is enabled on binary fields with the `attachment=True` parameter, as it is done for [`res.partner`'s `image` fields](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/3705a868d1188905dc9c090d57727ba1cd0926b5/openerp/addons/base/res/res_partner.py#L252-L262).

When active, the `get()` and `set()` method of the binary fields will [store and retrieve the value](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/3705a868d1188905dc9c090d57727ba1cd0926b5/openerp/addons/base/res/res_partner.py#L252-L262) in the `ir.attachment` table. If you look at the [code](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/3705a868d1188905dc9c090d57727ba1cd0926b5/openerp/addons/base/res/res_partner.py#L252-L262), you will see that the attachments use the following values to establish the link to the original record:

- `name`: name of the binary field, e.g. `image`
- `res_field`: name of the binary field, e.g. `image`
- `res_model`: model containing the field, e.g. `res.partner`
- `res_id`: ID of the record the binary field belongs to
- `type`: `'binary'`
- `datas`: virtual field with the contents of the binary field, which is actually stored on disk

So if you'd like to retrieve the `ir.attachment` record holding the value of the `image` of `res.partner` with ID 32, you could use the following SQL:

```sql
SELECT id, store_fname FROM ir_attachment
WHERE res_model = 'res.partner' AND res_field = 'image' AND res_id = 32;
```

Because `ir_attachment` entries use the filesystem storage by default, the actual value of the `store_fname` field will give you the path to the image file inside your Odoo filestore, in the form `'ab/abcdef0123456789'` where the `abc...` value is the SHA-1 hash of the file. This is how Odoo implements de-duplication of attachments: several attachments with the same file will map to the same unique file on disk.

If you'd like to modify the value of the `image` field programmatically, it is strongly recommended to use the ORM API (e.g. the [`write()`](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/9.0/reference/orm.html#openerp.models.Model.write) method), to avoid creating inconsistencies or having to manually re-implement the file storage system.

**References**

- Here is the [original 9.0 commit](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/commit/1bb61c970ed63eabe3821d21f3ed6f99c4b16daa) that introduces the feature for storing binary fields as attachments
- And the [9.0 commit](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/commit/5232fb9e24ee8be9fc90bb6b8aae03e2cfacfc8f) that converts the `image` field of res.partner to use it.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) Can you please also tell me which table is used to link that data in attachment and res_partner table? where is the relation that bind attachment for res_partner image?

Comment: You're welcome! The table that links the data in `ir.attachment` with the lines of `res.partner` is the `ir_attachment` table itself. Its columns `res_model`, `res_field` and `res_id` create a sort of `many2one` relationship to `res_partner` or to any other table which has a binary field with `attachment=True`. I have added an example of a SQL query you can use to retrieve the attachment for a given partner, and some explanation to find the actual image file on the filestore.

Comment: @odony I know it's a really old question but maybe you remember how is attachments linked in Odoo 8? because there is no 'res_field'